# Is there a way to prevent an element from losing focus in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

The focusout/blur events fire only after the element loses focus...
By the way, I prefer to do that without using plugins.

Comment: On the blur event, set the focus on the element again.

Comment: jQuery ***is*** a plug-in...

Comment: this seems like a user hostile thing to do. What is it you're trying to accomplish, or prevent?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah. You can use this:

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.focus();" />
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$(element).blur(function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Just one minor corner case I would mention: 
This method won't work when there is only one focusable control on the page. In this case it will focus on the url line of the browser.
To prevent this, you may create a out-of-screen control:
`<div style="position: absolute; top: -100px; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <input id="myDummyInput"/>
</div>`
The caveat of it that when you allow focus traverse, this control will be in the focus loop. (You can dynamically include or exclude this to avoid loosing the focus.)

Comment: @Balage1551 Nice idea, can you add it as a suggestion, I am happy to approve it. 

Comment: I have to test it, because my hack seems not to work in FF (the only widely used browser not running on chromium). So I need to find out how to trick it there.

Comment: A minimal delay helped on FF. Now the solution is tested on Chrome, Edge and FF.

Comment: @Balage1551 Ah, okay. But have it documented, along with your concerns too. It's all about research right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

When you click on a focusable DOM element (focusable by default, or made focusable by adding the `tabIndex` attribute to it), then it will first receive a `"focus"` event to let you know that it's about to receive the focus.

Before that, however, whatever had the focus will receive a `"focusout"` event of type `FocusEvent`.  Suppose your event variable is `e`.  The `e.relatedTarget` property will be populated with the element that's about to receive the focus.  If you handle the `"focusout"` event by setting the focus back to the thing that's losing the focus `e.target`, then it will immediately re-receive the focus, along with a `"focus"` and `"focusin"` event, while the object that was going to receive the focus will neither receive the focus nor any focus events.

Handling the `"focusout"` event, therefore, is the best way to prevent an object from *losing* the focus.  Technically, because the event is not `cancelable`, you cannot prevent it from losing the focus, but you can force it to immediately re-receive the focus, thereby preventing the focus from being transfered to another element.

Meanwhile, if your intent is to prevent an object from *receiving* the focus, then you're best bet is to handle its `"focus"` event by calling `blur` on the element, so it never receives the focus nor receives a `"focusin"` event.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the refocus solution works, but it fails when there is only one focusable element on the page, because the own controls of the browser is also in the tab order, and focusing on them can't be revoked.

So we need a hack to trick the browser: we should add a dummy, out-of-screen control to our page:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: -100px; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <input id="__myDummyInput"/>
</div>
```

It is important that this control should be **after** the real control in tab order!

Now we could apply the code on `onblur` or even better on `onfocuslost` event:

```js
 i.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
          setTimeout(() => e.target.focus(), 1)
        } else {
          e.target.focus()
        }
      })
```

Note: On Firefox the direct focus call doesn't work, so we need to add a minimal delay. However, it could produce some *blinking*.