# How can I prevent firebase Web UI from scrolling down to the login section automatically?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When a user opens my website, I don't want the site scrolling down to the 'login' section automatically.  I think that Firebase is scrolling down to the section when I perform:

```
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
```

http://launchpad.behavioralsight.com/

How can I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like FirebaseUI can be configured to prevent scrolling. There is an open Github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/751) (and related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984967/117030)).

The scrolling happens in [`setupFocus_()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/search?l=JavaScript&q=setupFocus_). There are several versions depending on the widget type, but I think you are interested in [passwordsignup.js](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/1a8f9e523f76df7a6c5da36b63b4d2a5b34b64ef/javascript/ui/page/passwordsignup.js#L92-L124).

The fix is quite simple: pass the `preventScroll` option to every call of  [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) like this:

```
this.getEmailElement().focus({preventScroll:true});
```

If you want to get fancy, you can make this a configurable option of the `AuthUI.start()` method as suggested in the Github issue.

---

If you don't want to modify FirebaseUI, a work-around based on this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42032209/117030) may work:

1. Manually focus another element on your site (like the button.)
2. Handle the `focusout` event as described in the answer above:

> Before that, however, whatever had the focus will receive a
> `"focusout"` event of type `FocusEvent`.  Suppose your event variable
> is `e`.  The `e.relatedTarget` property will be populated with the
> element that's about to receive the focus.  If you handle the
> `"focusout"` event by setting the focus back to the thing that's
> losing the focus `e.target`, then it will immediately re-receive the
> focus, along with a `"focus"` and `"focusin"` event, while the object
> that was going to receive the focus will neither receive the focus nor
> any focus events.

3. Then remove this `focusout` handler so the login section can be focused after the initial auto focus.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It is preventing the field from even receiving focus since it isn't visible on the screen.  Then after a second display the form.

HTML

```
<style>
  .loading #ui-sign-in-email-input { display: none; }
</style>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container" class="loading"></div>
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
```

JavaScript

```
...
uiShown: () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('firebaseui-auth-container').classList.remove('active');
  }, 500);
  document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
},
```

...